# Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. If $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $|s_{n+1} - s_n| < 2^{-n}$, show that $(s_n)$ is cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. If $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $|s_{n+1} - s_n| < 2^{-n}$, show that $(s_n)$ is cauchy

I've only gotten thus far:

Suppose $n > m > N$.

$|s_n-s_m| = |(s_n - s_{n-1}) + (s_{n-1} - s_{n-2}) + \ldots + (s_{m+1} - s_m)|$

$\leq |s_n - s_{n-1}| + |s_{n-1} - s_{n-2}| \ldots |s_{m+1} - s_m|$

$\leq (n-1)2^{-(n-1)} + (n-2)2^{-(n-2)} + \ldots + m2^{-m}$

$= 2^{-m}(m + 2^{-1}(m+1) + 2^{-2}(m+2) + \ldots + 2^{n-m+1}(n-m+1))$

Comment: More generally, if $(s_n)$ is such that $\sum |s_{n+1}-s_{n}|<+\infty$, $(s_n)$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.
For $p\ge q$ we have
$$|s_p-s_q|\le\sum_{k=0}^{p-q-1}|s_{p-k}-s_{p-k-1}|\le \sum_{k=0}^{p-q-1}2^{k-p+1}=2^{1-p}\frac{2^{p-q}-1}{2-1}=2^{1-q}-2^{1-p}$$
but since the sequence $\left(2^{1-n}\right)_n$ is convergent then it's  Cauchy sequence and there for $\epsilon>0$ there's $n_0$ such that for $p\ge q\ge n_0$ we have
$$2^{1-q}-2^{1-p}<\epsilon$$